# Prolog variable gets no value

Tags: prolog

I've written the following code in prolog:

```
contains(L1, []).
contains(L1, [X | T2]) :- member(X, L1), contains(L1, T2).

minus(L, [], L).
minus(L1, L2, L3) :- contains(L1, L3), nomembers(L3, L2).

nomembers(L1, []).
nomembers(L1, [X | T2]) :- not(member(X, L1)), nomembers(L1, T2).
```

`contains(L1, L2)` returns true if all of the members in `L2` appear in `L1`. (`contains([1,2],[1,1,1])` is true).

`minus(L1, L2, L3)` returns true if `L3=L1\L2`, meaning `L3` consists of members of `L1` but not of `L2`.

When I ask `minus([1,2,3,4],[2,1],L)`, I get the answer that `L=[]`, although logically it should be `L=[3,4]`. Does someone know why?

Comment: The problem is with `contains/2`. Although `contains/2` gives the right response when both variables are instantiated, if you query, say, `contains([a,b], L)` it will generate `L=[]`, then `L=[a]`, then `L=[a,a]`, etc. So the query `contains(L1, L3)` in your `minus/3` predicate isn't doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above comment of mbratch is very helpful.

Notice, that your current `minus(L1, L2, L3)` definition is: All members of `L3` are in `L1` and no member from `L3` is in `L2`.

Prolog is giving you good answer with `L3 = []`, it fits for definition I wrote above.

**EDIT**: Below code should do what you want, but currently I don't have prolog on my computer, so I can't test it.

```
remove(X, [X|T], T) :- !.
remove(X, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- remove(X, T, T2).

minus(L1,[],L1).
minus(L1,[H|T2],T3) :- member(H, L1), !, remove(H,L1,L4), minus(L4, T2, T3).
minus(L1,[H|T2],[H|T3]) :- minus(L1, T2, T3).
```

`remove(X,LA,LB)` which says: `LB` is `LA` without it first occurrence of `X`, so it's just removing element from the list.

Comment: The code doesn't work but it gives me another thought direction. I'll try to work it out later. Thanks :)

Comment: Check it now. It should be good now, tested on `swi-prolog`. `: )`

Comment: @DanDv If it satisfies you, please check my answer as accepted - "tick" mark near my answer.